# Error while running 'modprobe -v usb-storage' during 16.04 install

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, usb-drive, modprobe

This is a server which already has 32 bit Ubuntu 14 installed but I would like to reinstall with 64 bit which it does support. I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 as I have done many times before but this time I am running into an error.

```
Configuring d-i
Error while running 'modprobe -v usb-storage'
```

This error shows after selecting language, location and keyboard layout. I am installing from an 8gb usb drive which I have tried formatting it in different ways but still run into this error, I have also used 2 different external usb hard drives instead of the 8gb usb drive to see if they would work, same error. When formatting I have followed this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx which describes how to make a bootable usb on OSX using UNetbootin.

If I press continue after this error it will say "Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. ..."

I have tried different USB ports, even changing ports and then seeing if the installation would continue but with no luck.

In my BIOS settings Legacy USB support is set to auto, Intel xHCI mode is enabled and EHCI Hand-off is enabled. I have tried switching these settings on and off but it does not seem to change anything. The usb stick shows up without any problems and I am able to boot from it and begin the installation.

When searching for this error on Google I am unable to find any information related to this error during install.

**What are some other things I can try in order to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple boot options for the same usb stick. I had previously selected the usb stick with UEFI and found another option for the same device in the boot menu without UEFI which did not cause the same issue when trying to install.